# What is the "length" in the char[]?

Tags: java

```
char[] name = "VIKKYHACKS".toCharArray();
System.out.println(name.length);
```

In this program what is the "length" , If it were `(new String("VIKKYHACKS")).length()` then the length would be a method. But char[] is a datatype and cannot have fields or methods inside it. How does the second line of that program work ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

char[] is not a primitive data type. it is an Object, and it has a public field 'length'.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

That is a good start.

Because Arrays are Objects, they have all the other items, like an equals() and hashCode() method too. (as well as all the treats like notify(), wait(), etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are Objects in Java.  According to the JLS, [section 10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3), `length` is a "`final` instance variable" that gives the array's length.

Comment: +1 for not only giving the correct answer, but giving a link to the appropriate part in the Java Language Specification (JLS).

Answer (score 2):

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.You can use the built-in length property to determine the size of any array.
See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

First you have a string "VIKKYHACKS". Then you turn that into an array with the following

```
char[] name = "VIKKYHACKS".toCharArray();
```

"*char[] name =* " part, assigns our char array to the variable name. Which has the type char array (*char[]*)

Arrays have a variable named length which is accessed using .length. Which is used in the second line.

```
name.length
```

Answer (score 1):

every array has "length" variable instance which contains size of array (were talking about java :) )

Answer (score 1):

`length` is a `public final` field of the Array class. Its value is initialized upon creation of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Because name is an character array and arrays have property called length that fetches you the length of the array.
In case of string,length() is a method which gets you the length of the string.